# How do I 'logarize' my spectrogram output?

Tags: python, spectrogram

I'm building a spectrogram for some audio files that takes dB values for each bin as an array and visualizes them as brightness in a particular color. However, the output color is far too bright for values that should be basically invisible (-84dB). This makes me think my arrays need to be made more logarithmic in color processing.

How can I acomplish this to make the colors more perceptually accurate?

The spectrogram's input arrays something looks like

`[-1.007509747, -0.7208286419, -0.6967760266, -0.6406339168, -0.6272313747]`

and the rgb value of each bins pixels is determined through a hscToRgb function

`rgb = hsvToRgb(.25, 1-Math.abs(v), 1-Math.abs(v));`

where the last two inputs determine color intensity and brightness.